# Query works in MySQL not Oracle

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle, ora-00923

The following SQL statement works in MySQL but not with Oracle:

```
SELECT *, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_A
```

Oracle complaint: "FROM keyword not found where expected"

---

actually the statement was incorrect, we were not grouping by COLUMN_A but another column instead. actually what we want is this

```
SELECT *, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_B

this works but gives us only column A and B

SELECT COLUMN_B, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_B

what we want is this, but it doesn't work (group by error)

SELECT COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C .... COLUMN_X, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_B
```

Comment: Correct.  You'll have to adjust the query.

Comment: Could you describe what you are actually trying to achieve. This statement does not really make sense at all

Answer (score 3):

That's because Oracle requires you to define all the columns not wrapped in an aggregate function (MIN, MAX, COUNT, etc).  SQL Server would return a similar error.  [MySQL's behavior is documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Because your query is using `SELECT *`, I can't re-write it properly for you.  But I also can't guarantee a syntactically correct version would return the same results as you see on MySQL either.  Grouping by the same column you want the MAX is quite odd...

Comment: Actually all DBMS except MySQL will refuse to run such a query. MySQL simply returns indeterminate results

Comment: actually the statement was incorrect, we were not grouping by COLUMN_A but another column instead. actually what we want is this

<code>
SELECT *, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_B

this works but gives us only column A and B

SELECT COLUMN_B, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_B

what we want is this, but it doesn't work (group by error)

SELECT COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C .... COLUMN_X, MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100 
GROUP BY COLUMN_B
</code>

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, SQLite supports the same "hidden column" functionality that MySQL supports.  But any *real* database, yes - you're correct. :)

Comment: @Dave: Update your question with example data, output from `DESC table_xyz`, and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the max() for column_a you don't need the group by at all:

```
SELECT MAX(COLUMN_A) 
  FROM table_xyz 
 WHERE COLUMN_A <= 100
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone else is saying, Oracle does not allow mixing `*` with explicit column definitions in queries:

```
SQL> select *, table_name from user_tables;
select *, table_name from user_tables
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Oracle hasn't even looked at the fact that you are trying to get columns outside of those included in the `group by` clause. Which as others have stated, Oracle will not do.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your MAX issue, but the only way to follow a '*' with other columns is if you use an explicit reference to a table alias - e.g.

```
 SELECT e.*, zip_code
 FROM  addresses a,
       employees e
 WHERE e.addressId = a.Id
```

For the MAX value, you will either need to group by all other columns, or look into analytic functions (plenty of previous answers on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems. Your GROUP BY clause is backwards. You need to define your GROUP BY by the columns in the *. Also what OMG Ponies said before.